# google auth redirect uri miss match issue

Tags: django, google-api, google-apps

In my django project i want to use google authentication for user login. i followed some articles but now stuck at point, where i'm getting error like: Error: redirect_uri_mismatch. i searched allot but could not resolved this issue. plz help
I'm sharing my code here:

```py
settings.py


import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


SECRET_KEY = 'xnph^f^z=wq^(njfp*#40^wran3'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []




INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social_django',
    'core',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',  # <--

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'simple.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',  # <--
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'


SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'simple.wsgi.application'



SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'xxxxxx my key xXXXXXX'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'xxx my secrete XXXX'




DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

```py
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('^oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),  # <--
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

```py
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block contents %}
  <h2>Login</h2> 
  <br> 
 <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">Login with Google</a><br>

{% endblock %}
```

link of my Google App settings

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rX8JEcTSQU8IXubkxWkbAPsG_ka0t76s

Comment: have you migrated after adding the social_django app?

Comment: @Exprator yes i migrated. And same thing i tried for Github Auth, which is working right

Comment: ok, so the redirect uri you have given in google api, should be `localhost:8000/home/` or else put the url there where it will be redirected after loggin from google. you have given only localhost:8000

Answer (score 0):

try with this,

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ='/complete/google-oauth2/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True ,
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mypage.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

this works for me

google need to know if you are using a a https and the address after login and yo must allow your domain access